# Does anyone know the name of this Hindu deity?

Tags: gods, identification-request

[image]

Does anyone know the name of this Hindu deity? Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: from the serpent above and the lionlike face it is probably Lord Narasmiha - http://anudinam.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Lakshmi-Narasimhar.jpg. Namaste, All the best

Comment: Thank you so much @Sai . A quick search for  Lord Narasmiha statues on google and I even found where the statue is located (Hampi).

Comment: ugra narasimha..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lord Narasimha, the incarnation of Lord Vishnu with a Lion's face and a human body is worshipped across India. [Here](http://hampi.in/story-of-narasimha) is a reference for the same.

[image]

The serpent is Lord Adi Sesha or the divine thousand hooded snake, on whom Lord Vishnu rests.

All the best.

Answer (score 6):

The deity shown in the picture is Lord Yogananda Narasimha a specific form of Narasimha, the man lion incarnation of Lord Vishnu. This form is worshipped by devotees (as a part of upasana) to attain knowledge in Yoga and to increase concentration. This is a peaceful form of Lord Narasimha. The serpent is Adi Shesha, the serpent bed of Lord Vishnu.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Namaste

The deity shown may be that of Yakshagana for the murti is shown as holding / writing an manuscript.  Vijayanagara empire is known in history for encouraging literature, knowledge & arts.  Yakshagana are known to be quiz masters of hindu mythology & knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

The Deity shown is is Lord Yogananda Narasimha a specific form of Narasimha, the man lion incarnation of Lord Vishnu.  The image is probably from the ruins of Vijayanagara empire.  A temple of the same Deity is placed in the precincts of Tirumala Tirupathi Temple to the right of the sanctum sanctorum.